# Trouble with recursion in list sorting (C)

Tags: c, recursion

For school we are doing a list sort. We have to use this exact function structure per assignment, swapping the last element of the list with the largest, recursively, until the list is processed. I have tested my solution and it works up until the recursion, at which point it core dumps and exits.

here is my function

```
void selection_sort(int array[], int length){

    if (length <= 0)return;

    int largest = array[0], place_holder, i;

    for(i = 0; i < length; i ++){
        if (array[i] > largest){ //finds the largest number
            largest = array[i];
            place_holder = i; //marks where it was found
        }
    }
    array[place_holder] = array[length - 1];//places n-1th element into space of largest number
    array[length - 1] = largest;//places largest element into n-1th place

    selection_sort(array, length - 1);
}
```

maybe I don't fully understand recursion.

Comment: What is the length of the array? Is the stack limit sufficient for the length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`place_holder` may be uninitialized at `array[place_holder]`. Initialize it like this:

```
    int largest = array[0], place_holder = 0, i; /* add "= 0" */
```

Comment: yes thank you that was it. once the function started with the largest number place_holder never gets initialized

Comment: My comment was obviously not correct.  removed it and +1